# Como fazer thumbnail de um PDF?

Tags: thumbnail

Bom, estou desenvolvendo um projeto de compartilhamento de materiais digitais, onde os usuários poderão submeter artigos, apresentações e outros. Dito isso queria saber, como posso fazer um thumbnail desses documentos submetidos ?

Comment: Que linguagem de programação você está utilizando?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se tu quer mesmo uma thumb de um documento .pdf, pode converter esse doc em imagem e aí gerar thumb. Tem várias libs que fazem isso.

Já trabalhei com a ImageMagick que faz isso, e é free:

http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/

Mas a lib é enorme pra uma funcionalidade assim...

A PDFSharp, não tenho certeza que converte pdf pra image, mas tu pode dar uma olhada: https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp, só usei essa pra converter imagem pra .pdf.

E tem: https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1, que é free, leve e fácil de usar.

Tu pode ler mais a respeito:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-a-jpg-image/

https://www.print-driver.com/how-to/convert-pdf-to-jpg

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42287/Convert-PDF-pages-to-image-files-using-the-Solid-F

Sei que não é o que tu pediu, mas, não daria só pra ter uma imagem, ou vetor, de algo que remetesse a extensão e adicionar pra todos os arquivos? Isso não comprometeria em nada o seu processamento e tu poderia indicar o arquivo pelo nome, mas, só uma sugestão. (=

Ah, e só te dei alternativas em .net pq tu não especificou a linguagem.

Comment: Pois é não especifiquei haha, mas saberia de algo em PHP ?

Comment: ImageMagick: http://us3.php.net/imagick e ghostScript: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/ (=